# How do you add enum labels using sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a table called characters. Each character has an enum called "state", which can be "sad" or "happy". How do I add a new state "confused" to my column? I tried this migration but it failed:

```
migration.describeTable('characters').success(function (attributes) {
    migration.changeColumn('characters', 'state',
        {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM,
            values: ['sad', 'happy', 'confused']
        })
        .complete(done);
});
```

It complained that error: type "enum_characters_state" already exists.

Answer (score 16):

Expanding on briangonzalez answer, you will also need a down function to undo the migration:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TYPE enum_type_name ADD VALUE 'new_value'");
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    var query = 'DELETE FROM pg_enum ' +
      'WHERE enumlabel = \'new_value\' ' +
      'AND enumtypid = ( SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = \'enum_type_name\')';
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(query);
  }
};
```

change **enum_type_name** and **new_value** to fit your needs.

Comment: That's the most accurate and complete answer, this should be the one accepted for this question.

Answer (score 8):

With the latest version of Sequelize, you could achieve this by running a query (Postgres assumed):

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TYPE enum_character_state ADD VALUE 'confused';");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

create a migration with following script:

```
module.exports = {
  up  : function (queryInterface) {
    return queryInterface
      .changeColumn(tableName, columnName, {
        values: arrayOfNewValues
      });
  },
  down: function (queryInterface) {
    return queryInterface
      .changeColumn(tableName, columnName, {
        values: arrayOfOldValues
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: This should be the accepted one. It's the less database-dependant solution.

Comment: This one doesn't work for me with PostgreSQL - it complains that the enum type already exists.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I am not late to the party..

this works for me

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
      ALTER TYPE "enum_type_name" ADD VALUE 'confused';
    `);
  },

  down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
      ALTER TYPE "enum_type_name" DROP VALUE 'confused';
    `);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the type, if you want to re-add it. Useful in down migrations if nothing else.

```
queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP TYPE enum_characters_state;')
```