# After add more options to ENUM field, does the whole database have to be rebuilt?

Tags: sequelize.js

My database in nodejs/express is defined with Sequelizejs 6.x. Here is a ENUM field `status`:

```
status: { type: DataTypes.ENUM('active', 'blocked', 'inactive', 'pending', 'unverified', 'selfdeleted', 'deleted'),
          allowNull:false,
          defaultValue:'unverified'
},
```

I just added 2 more options `deleted` and `selfdeletd` to `status` ENUM.  Do I have to rebuild the database after ENUM option addition? Or I just need to update the definition of the model and no need to rebuild the whole database.

Comment: Based on my try, it is not working. The value has to be added to the ENUM before it can be assign. Here is a post about how to add ENUM value. https://blog.yo1.dog/updating-enum-values-in-postgresql-the-safe-and-easy-way/

Comment: You should use the sequelize migration with `ALTER TYPE` query. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75621512/2956135

If you are not familiar with sequelize migration -> https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/